# Grid minor in digraphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-minor

Thor Johnson, et al, in their paper: [Directed Tree Width](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/dirtree.pdf), introduced a definition for directed grid $J_k$, and they conjectured:

> $(5.1)$ For every integer $k$ there exists an integer $N$ such that every
>   digraph with tree-width $N$ or more has a minor isomorphic to $J_k$.

And they continued by saying:

> We have convinced ourselves that $(5.1)$ holds for planar digraphs,
>   but the general case is open.

And I'm looking for this unpublished paper (how they proved the conjecture for di-planar graphs), or related stuff in this case, actually how to use such a grid (I mean $J_k$).

Comment: Did you already contact the authors about that? I'd be curious about that, too. To me, the statement "We have convinced ourselves" does not necessarily imply that they had a fully worked out version of their argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a new preprint by Stephan Kreutzer and Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi, in which they apparently show that the statement (5.1) is true for all digraphs.

Stephan Kreutzer and Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi: [The directed grid theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5681v1.pdf).    arXiv:1411.5681 [cs.DM]

**EDIT (June 16, 2015):**

A short version of their paper appears here:

Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi, Stephan Kreutzer. The Directed Grid Theorem. In: Rocco A. Servedio, Ronitt Rubinfeld (eds.), Proceedings of the Forty-Seventh Annual ACM on Symposium on Theory of Computing 2015. pp. 655-664

Answer (score 8):

Johnson et al shown that the planar digraphs are excluding $J_K$ as minor, but they never published this paper, because they were looking to generalize this result. But recently Ken-Ichi Kawarabayashi and Stephan Kreutzer proved "An Excluded Grid Theorem for Digraphs with Forbidden Minors" [SODA2014](http://www.siam.org/meetings/da14/da14_accepted.pdf), which generalizes grid theorem on planar directed graphs by Johnson et al. to digraphs with fix undirected minor excluded.

**EDIT:** The aforementioned paper is now publicly available:

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611973402.6

Johnson et al. 2001 paper, now is publicly available:

[Excluding A Grid Minor In Planar Digraphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00473)

Comment: I am interested in hearing about these results. I would appreciate you providing the recent references. Did you get the draft paper from Seymour etal?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri, Actually someone else got draft paper (many years ago), and some days ago I just take a look at paper for few hours. on the first page, one of a main authors wrote "Do not distribute". so we cannot expect to have it, but new result is going to publish in SODA2013, and I can refer to this new result (when published).